# How to deploy nextjs app using pm2 on cent OS 7.9 server?

Tags: nginx, linux, centos

I am facing trouble in Cent OS though.

I install nginx using `yum install nginx`
Now the folders in nginx were missing, so I created `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`.

Then edited `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and added

```
http {
 ...
 ...
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
}
```

Now made the conf in `sites-available`
`nano webgenie`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Now I created the linking using
`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/webgenie /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webgenie`

I cloned the repo, did `npm run build` then did
`pm2 start npm --name "nextapp" -- start`
I still see this, when I go to URL
[image]